# Swiper slider gallery, and changing orientation on Iphone's

Tags: javascript, iphone, responsive-design, orientation-changes, swiper.js

I made an image gallery format. It's responsive (boostrap and some own medias @), when i click an image, a Swiper (http://idangero.us/ plugin) slider opens to show images one by one in a bigger size. I tested on PC, and Android phones, and it's working fine on this 2 devices:

responsive, changing orientation on phone (android), all formats are working fine...

except iphones, when i click an image, it opens fine, but when orientation is changed, it doesnt resize the swiper area.

I allready try this 2 options:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    mySwiper.update(); and thisone: mySwiper.onResize();
});
```

Also i notice this, after changing orientation (landscape to portrait OR portrait to landscape), and do a small scroll-down, swiper resize the container (the scroll to hide the addres-bar upside) and works fine, but in android, that's not necesary.

Answer (score 2):

It's look like a huck, but it's worked for me:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function () {
  setTimeout(() => swiper.onResize(), 50);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar trouble when using Swiper (4.4.6). On iOS after an orientation change, Swiper appeared to be "confused" as to how many slider elements it contained and would let me slide beyond the final element. Although the OP stated it didn't work for him, I had success with:

```
$(window).on( 'orientationchange', function()
{
    mySwiper.update();
} );
```

I happened to be using jQuery, but I'm sure it would have worked as well using DOM only.

Be sure to change the reference to "mySwiper" to whatever your Swiper instance global variable is named!